# Java Binary search tree implementation

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Stack_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String val;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Text: ");
        val = input.nextLine();
        push(val);
    }

    public static void push(String str) {
        Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            stk.push(str.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(stk);
        String reverseString = "";
        String original = "";
        int length = original.length();
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverseString = reverseString + original.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
        if (original.toUpperCase().equals(stk))
            System.out.println("The string is a palindrome.");
        else if (reverseString.toUpperCase().equals(stk))
            System.out.println("The string is not a palindrome.");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out. I didn't know where I went wrong. The question was to create a stack (Character), and display the text where it is a palindrome or not. The user had to enter input.

P.S This was one of my lab test.

Comment: Does the title of this question have anything to do with checking whether a String is a palindrome?

Comment: Post a [mcve], you can't just post code and say "fix it".

Comment: I just need guidance and advice on how i could improve my code. From there i can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed the code correctly, the problem appears to be that the OP is comparing a `String` object (either `original` or `reverseString`) to `Stack<Character>` object.

So, the probable failure is the incorrect attempted comparison of a `String` object to a `Stack` object.

I think there is a 2nd failure in the `if/else if` logic given that an example input of "cool" is not a palindrome, but no output is produced in such a case.

**EDIT:** while the OP code does attempt to adjust for the case of the entered data (not given in the question as to whether that is a requirement or not), it does not account for spaces or other punctuation. According to [the entry on Wikipedia about Palindromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome), punctuation is also usually ignored. Again, whether being concerned about spaces, periods, dashes, etc. was part of the exercise is not defined in the question. The question is a bit under specified in terms of full requirements.

I would think a solution using a stack would take a `String`, push it by character to a `Stack` (probably correcting for case and stripping out all punctuation at that time), and then do a comparison by popping from the `Stack`. I think the OP code is missing part of the requirement in using a `Stack`.

Example code to have only characters on the `Stack`. There are other approaches, of course:

```
// push by character onto the stack; use only
//  characters, and convert to lower case
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if ( (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ) {
         stk.push(Character.toLowerCase(c));
    }
}
```

Example to remove all non characters from a check String:

```
// convert out comparison String to lower case and remove
// all non letters
String chk = str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
```

Example loop to use the `Stack` to check against the String:

```
    // assume we have a palindrome
    boolean palindrome = true;
    // counter across the String
    int i = 0;

    // loop while there is more on the stack and we haven't
    // failed our test
    while (! stk.isEmpty() && palindrome) {
        Character c = stk.pop();
        palindrome = (c == chk.charAt(i++));
    }
```

Sample Test Data:

> cool is a palindrome: false
>   mom is a palindrome: true
>   Never odd or even is a palindrome: true
>   A man, a plan, a canal - Panama! is a palindrome: true